# Can BreezeJS work with MySQL + NodeJS + AngularJS?

Tags: mysql, node.js, angularjs, breeze

I'd like to use breeze but I can't find out if it will work with a MySQL + Express + Angular + Node stack. The docs say it will work with MongoDB, but what about MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@danilodeveloper I'm having to take back your answer because it isn't that simple.

There currently is **no** out-of-the-box support for Breeze + Node + MySQL. Simply using `node-mysql` to interface with the DB isn't enough. As per Ward's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23638600/how-to-get-breezejs-to-talk-to-mysql-db-with-angular-node) not using an `ORM` would be tricky and a ton of code would need to be written along the lines of the [breeze-mongodb npm module](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.server.node).

Answer (score 0):

> Any standard SQL database like Oracle, MySQL, MariaDB, SQLServer, etc is supported out of the box as long as there is an Entity Framework Provider for it (and almost all of them do).
>   [Source](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/faq#database)

You can integrate the Nodejs backend with Mysql using, for example [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql), and to integrate with Angularjs, you can do something like this:

```
<!-- Angular template -->
<li data-ng-repeat="emp in employees">
    <label>{{emp.FirstName}}</label>
    <label>{{emp.LastName}}</label>
</li>

// bound to employees from query
manager.executeQuery(breeze.EntityQuery.from("Employees"))
       .then(function(data) { $scope.employees = data.results; });
```

Comment: In the FAQ, should of known. This pretty much answers it but I want to give it a test drive first. From the FAQ I found [Handcuffed to Microsoft?](http://www.breezejs.com/blog/handcuffed-microsoft) which also helped.

Comment: Wow, that FAQ is old!  Entity Framework is definitely **not** a requirement.  The [Zza sample](http://www.breezejs.com/samples/zza) is the only one on Node so far, but there is a [Java sample using MySQL](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/tree/master/java)

Comment: I'm stumped on figuring out how to setup the API for breeze to talk to. I'll have to post another question on that.

Comment: Awesome. I'll try to help you there ;)

Comment: @danilodeveloper thanks! Here's the link to the question [How to get BreezeJS to talk to MySQL DB with Angular + Node?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23638600/how-to-get-breezejs-to-talk-to-mysql-db-with-angular-node)