# How to get BreezeJS to talk to MySQL DB with Angular + Node?

Tags: mysql, node.js, angularjs, breeze

Stack: MySQL + Express + Angular + Node and node-mysql to talk to the DB.

**EDIT:** I'm connectiong to a local DB and the connection works. I can't get Breeze to communicate with it.

I'm trying to get the Breeze Todo app to work with this setup but I'm getting a `localhost:3000/ToDos? 404 (Not Found)` when Breeze goes out to get the data.

Do I need to create the API for Breeze to talk to? I've tried this:

```
angular.module('mysql', ['ngResource']).
factory('ToDos', function($resource) {
    var ToDos = $resource('/ToDos', {}, {update:{method:'PUT'}});

    return ToDos
});
```

And then injecting it into the datacontext service here:

```
angular.module('mainApp').factory('datacontext', 
['$http', 'logger', 'breeze', 'ToDos', datacontext]);

function datacontext($http, logger) {

    var dataService = new breeze.DataService({
        serviceName: '/ToDos',
        hasServerMetadata: false
    });

    var manager = new breeze.EntityManager({
        dataService: dataService
    });
...
}
```

I'm pretty lost as to what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** The comments informed me that the backend API needs to be created.  I'm working on that but could use some help converting the `breeze-mongodb` module.

In Breeze's zza example in repository.js there are calls to this module's `MongoQuery()` and `MongoSaveHandler()` functions. Would it be as simple as converting them to MySQL `connection.query`? And any help in the conversion would be much appreciated!

Comment: Yes, you need to create the server-side API for Breeze to talk to.  Look at the [Zza-node-mongo](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/tree/master/node/zza-node-mongo/server) example to see how the server-side routes were set up in Express.  Your repository will be different, since you're using MySQL, but the rest can be similar.

Comment: Ok, that's what I was unsure of. I'll add all the `app.VERB('/ToDos', function (req, res) { ... };` code and see if I can get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very curious about your progress on this. It's quite ambitious.

Ultimately I believe you'll be writing something like the ["breeze-mongodb" npm module](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.server.node) which will have a query and save implementation attuned to MySQL.

It could be tricky without an ORM. If you choose to go with an ORM in Node for MySQL ([**node-orm**???](https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2)), you can learn a lot about what to do from the Breeze source code for `ContextProvider`, `ContextProvider.EF` and `ContextProvider.NH` in the  ["breeze.net.server" repo on github](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.server.net).  You don't have to be a C# person to glean transferable insights from that code base.

Comment: you'll be waiting a while... I'ts outside my realm ATM.